# How to use square pic controllers with breadboard

Tags: microcontroller, pic, breadboard

I've just started learning pic controllers and I'm collecting all the information. I've seen a lot of examples where people used breadboard with pic18. But I want to buy pic32 as the price is just a little higher. All pic32 are square. However, for my university project I want to use breadboard. And I can't understand how I can use this breadboard with square controller. Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a link to a picture of what you mean?

Comment: Google your part number plus "DIP breakout" (minus quotes) and see what you get.

Comment: http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/index.php?cPath=2200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that by "Square" you mean a surface mount (T)QFP type package. These parts are not designed for breadboard, and to be honest breadboards are evil anyway.

If you want to use one you would require a breakout board (PCB) which takes the surface mount pins and brings them out to breadboard friendly 0.1" headers. Depending on the number of pins such a thing may exist or it may not.

For a university project, you should seriously consider designing a PCB for this thing - a well designed PCB goes a long way to getting extra credit!

Answer (score 2):

"All pic32 are square" is incorrect. For example, this one http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=PIC32MX270F256B is available in DIP package, I have one on my bench right now, plugged into the breadboard.

Comment: Thank you. How did you find out that is not square. I mean there are a lot of items in microchip 32 catalogue and how is it possible to check that is not square without clicking each.

Comment: Parametric search. Last column shows available packages.